# Why doesn't INTEGER/INTEGER does not give me an answer in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I am trying to find the success rate of the messages received in SQL. Hence, I create a table with message id and action (sent or received) then I count the no. of received msgs/total no. of messages. Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE msg (id INTEGER, action TEXT);
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (1, 'sent');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (1, 'received');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (2, 'sent');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (2, 'received');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (3, 'sent');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (4, 'sent');
INSERT INTO msg VALUES (5, 'sent');

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT( DISTINCT id) AS success_rate FROM msg;
```

This gives me 0 as output. Why?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) It seems strange that `id` is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your database does integer division. Simple add a decimal point:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS success_rate
FROM msg;
```

I might want to divide by the number sent -- just in case:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'sent' THEN 1.0 END)
       ) AS success_rate
FROM msg;
```

Or by unique accounts in both cases:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN id END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT id)
       ) AS success_rate
FROM msg;
```

If `id` were unique (which seems reasonable to me), this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS success_rate
FROM msg;
```